# OCaml A ref does not change its value despite I instructed it

Tags: ocaml

I have a real code but I made this sample to illustrate my issue.
This is the code sample:

```
let ejem n =
  let count = ref 0 in
  let rec aum n =
    if n = 0 then 0
      else (count := !count + 1; n + aum (n-1) )
  in (aum n, !count)
```

I try to change the `count` value inside `aum` function but, despite the `count` is outside of this function, its value is always `0` once it finishes.

Please, help me to get what the issue is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OCaml doesn't guarantee any particular order of evaluating expressions.

In your last line you have this expression:

```
(aum n, !count)
```

It's completely legitimate for OCaml to evaluate the `!count` before the `aum n`, which will give the result you see.

To control evaluation order you can use `let`:

```
let res = aum n in
(res, !count)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jeffrey's answer, you could use the more idiomatic `incr count` instead of `count := !count + 1` and `pred n` instead of `n - 1`.
These functions are defined in the always opened [Stdlib](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stdlib.html) module.
You could even convert the recursive function *aum* to a [tail-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) function using an accumulator.

The improved *ejem* function will then be:

```
let ejem n =
  let count = ref 0 in
  let rec aum accu n =
    if n = 0 then
      accu
    else (
      incr count;
      aum (accu + n) (pred n)
    )
  in
  let res = aum 0 n in
  (res, !count)
```